# How do I get the full path of Content?

Tags: c#, monogame

To display an image from Content in a .NET Forms Dialog, I'm trying to make a function that loads an image through .NET's `Image.FromFile(string fileName)` function, but instead of taking a whole path, it takes the path you'd usually put in `Content.Load<T>(string assetName)`.

For this, I need to be able to get the complete root directory of the Content folder, but how do I get that?

I've already tried `Content.RootDirectory`, but that seems to give only a relative file path (in my case, it just says "Content" because I left it at default)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you need to understand to get this to work.

First, what you're trying to do will be platform specific. So I'm going to assume you're only concerned with getting it working on Windows.

Second, if you're adding content to the `Content.mgcb` file it will be compiled by MonoGame's Content Pipeline and it will end up in a `Content` folder as an XNB file relative to the executable.

For example, let's say you've added a `texture.png` file to your `Content.mgcb` file. When the game or tool runs the image will be compiled and end up in the following place by default.

```
 - Game.exe
 - Content
     - texture.xnb
```

This means that the path relative to your executable would be `Content\texture.xnb` and you could use the regular C# method `Path.GetFullPath("Content\texture.xnb")` to get the full path relative to the executable.

Of course, you won't be able to load an XNB file with `Image.FromFile(string fileName)` because it's not a standard image format. To deal with that what you'll probably want to do is copy the original `texture.png` file to the output folder.

To do that you can use the Properties of the file and set the *Build Action* to **Content** and the *Copy to Output Directory* to **Copy if newer**.

[image: copy image to the output directory]

Now the `texture.png` file will be available to load relative to the executable.

```
 - Game.exe
 - Content
     - texture.png
```

Lastly, if you want to actually load this PNG file directly into MonoGame *without* using the `Content.Load` method you can write you're own method using `Texture2D.FromStream` like this:

```cs
public Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        var newTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, fileStream);
        PremultiplyTexture(newTexture);
        return newTexture;
    }
}

private static void PremultiplyTexture(Texture2D texture)
{
    var data = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];

    texture.GetData(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = Color.FromNonPremultiplied(data[i].R, data[i].G, data[i].B, data[i].A);

    texture.SetData(data);
}
```

Note: I've also included a method to pre-multiply the texture because this is something normally done by the MonoGame Content Pipeline. If you don't do this the texture won't work properly with `AlphaBlend` mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Aside from the ability to preview the image in a windows form, is there any advantage of using png files over resuming to build them with Monogame's pipeline tool?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "resuming to build them"?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant resuming to use MonoGame's Content Pipeline tool for managing them in xnb format instead of png. Like is there an advantage of using png's exclusively and circumventing the Content Pipeline Tool entirely?

Comment: The Content Pipeline essentially solves 2 problems. 1. It makes content cross platform by compiling it into a known format. 2. It sometimes adds extra information when processing it like premultiplying the alpha channel for rendering. If you want to bypass the Pipeline you can solve those problems yourself and a lot if the time you can easily enough. It really depends on the platforms you're targeting and what kind of content you need to load.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.dataPath` to get the folder of your game, the concatenate the string with "Assets\Resources" or wherever your pictures may be.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

Comment: I feel like now would be a good time to mention I'm not using Unity, but MonoGame. The only classes that seem close to it are `System.ApplicationId`, `System.ApplicationIdentity` and `System.ApplicationException`.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string contentPath = System.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\" + Content.RootDirectory;
```

Did the trick for me. Unfortunately, the files it'll give you are in a `.xnb` format, making it impossible to pass on to the image of a Windows Form.